# Adding a sublayer to a UIView (background view) of UITableViewCell covers other cell views?

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to add a gradient to a `UIView` that serves as a background (backgroundRect) of a `UITableViewCell`.  I expected the gradient to be drawn at the same Z position as the backgroundRect, however when building on device it obscures (over top of) my labels and other views.  What's confusing though is that when I use the ViewDebugger it shows my views as if they should appear with the gradient layer behind them?

```
class NewWorkoutTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var backgroundRect: UIView!

        @IBOutlet weak var dayOfTheWeekLabel: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var sessionTypeLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var sessionTypeImage: UIImageView!

        @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()

            backgroundRect.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0

            backgroundRect.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            backgroundRect.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            backgroundRect.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
            backgroundRect.layer.shadowRadius = 5

            // this is making a CoreAnimation gradient layer
            let gradient = CAGradientLayer() // Line 1

            // this is setting the dimensions of the gradient to the
            // same as the view that will contain it
            gradient.frame = backgroundRect.bounds // Line 2
            //gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.35]
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradient.endPoint =  CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)


            let iPhoneForegroundColor = UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.26, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)

            // this is setting the gradient from and to colors
            gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor,iPhoneForegroundColor.cgColor] // Line 3


            backgroundRect.layer.addSublayer(gradient) // Line 4


        }



    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `xib/storyboard` setup for this cell? Also the current and expected results with some images?

Comment: Sure thing see above @Kamran

Comment: Set `gradient.zPosition = -1`. Not sure if this will work but you can try. The issue is that all the ui elements are added in background rect so when you are adding gradient layer, it is being added on top of all those elements.

Comment: **backgroundRect.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)**

Comment: Hope this will work for you @GarySabo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use

```
backgroundRect.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Instead of using

```
backgroundRect.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I get a reference to this subLayer (at 0) so that I can add my drop shadow to it?  Otherwise the drop shadow is added to the layer below it?

Comment: Yiu are writting this code n awakeFromNib() which is called when cel is initiated , Thus whatever you want to add like gradientView or shadow to it , Write all this before you add this to mainLayer, Second option which I always use is creating different subclass of UIView such as **class GradientView: UIView { /// Add shadow here }** and use this class Object to add as subview and save extra load in one class

Answer (score 0):

Debug the UI and see if added layer covers the subviews... i think your layer covers the subviews.